# label position in stat_bin for geom_histogram: how to adress ..count.. in the position_nudge method?

Tags: r, label, stat, geom-histogram

I've got input_values as a tibble:
[input_values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQpE7.png)

For these alues I'd like to plot a histogram, where the columns are labeled (90° angle, almost directly on top of the colums).

```
as_tibble(input_values) %>% ggplot(aes(x = values) + geom_histogram(stat = "bin") + stat_bin(geom='text', angle = 90, family = "Calibri", hjust=-1, vjust=0.4, aes(label=..count..))
```

[image: [this is the result (plus a bit styling)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvjDu.png)]

the label is always positioned too high. I reckon something like "stat_bin(..., position = position_nudge(y = ..count..*-0.1)) would do the trick. But I cannot address my count values in this manner, for the x it seems to work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014450/geom-histogram-and-stat-bin-dont-align)

I tried also stat = count, position = position_nudge(y = 1000) etc. but it didn't work because the labels are more further up, the higher the count was.

Comment: sorry for the images, I couldnt get the code block to work (either)

                     values
[1,]              0.1939713
[2,]              0.2042603
[3,]              0.2191685
[4,]              0.2346884
...

the code

as_tibble(input_values) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = values) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "bin") +
  stat_bin(geom='text', angle = 90, family = "Calibri", hjust=-1, vjust=0.4,
           aes(label=..count..))

Comment: simply copy your code and set off using ```. Also provide some data. Use `dput(input)` and paste the result assigned to an object

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have set `hjust=-1`. As you rotated your labels set `hjust=0` to align the labels with the top of the bars, then use `position = position_nudge(...)` to shift them. Also note that I use `after_stat` instead of the `..` notation as the latter was deprecated in `ggplot2 >= 3.4.0`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

input_values <- data.frame(
  values = rnorm(3e6)
)

ggplot(input_values, aes(x = values)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "bin") +
  stat_bin(
    geom = "text", angle = 90, family = "Calibri",
    hjust = 0, position = position_nudge(y = 1000),
    aes(label = after_stat(count))
  )
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]